# The optimal number of buckets in Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, boto, botocore

I wonder that what is the behavior of Amazon S3 by increasing number of buckets? supposedly, according to documentation:

> By default, you can create up to 100 buckets in each of your AWS accounts. If you need additional buckets, you can increase your account bucket limit to a maximum of 1,000 buckets by submitting a service limit increase. There is no difference in performance whether you use many buckets or just a few.

So I am curious about the plot of S3 performance based on the number of buckets.

Comment: "there is no difference in performance"

Comment: But when try to find a object it calculate hash of object's key. so when the number of buckets is as much as possible there would be a large hash space and so it would have impact on find operations.

Comment: Or maybe it wouldn't. I'd trust amazon documentation. They built the thing, they know how it works and scales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit to the number of objects stored in a bucket. You could, in theory, do everything out of a single bucket. Or, perhaps one bucket per region.

When buckets have millions of objects, it can become very slow to list the contents of a bucket. This is where you could use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects.

Aside from listing the contents of a bucket, performance should not be impacted based on the size of the bucket. However, see: [Best Practices Design Patterns: Optimizing Amazon S3 Performance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/optimizing-performance.html)

Comment: The question was about the number of buckets not size of a bucket. As an example the performance of 1000 buckets is equal to the state with 100 buckets?

Comment: The number of buckets assigned to a single account will have no impact on anything. Amazon S3 has millions of customers and millions of buckets. Creating one more bucket has no impact on the performance of a bucket.